# Can errors result from using .py files with pythonw?

Tags: python

Easy quesiton here.  I have a GUI which I run using a batch file. I want it to be displayed with out the terminal in the background, so I use the pythonw executable.  However, I am not using the corresponding `.pyw` file, but a regular `.py` file instead.

Are there any differences between python and pythonw that might cause strange behavior.  The program gives strange behavior when I use the batch file, but not when within `cmd` so I suspect the culprit is some internal difference between python and pythonw.  Could this be the case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Gives strange behavior" is not a description that anyone can use to diagnose your problem.

Comment: The specific thing we noticed was that certain buttons needed to be pressed twice to work.  But I'm not asking for a diagnosis, I'm asking if the differences between python and pythonw cause them to be incompatible (cause bugs) with ```.py``` or ```.pyw``` files

Comment: More likely the difference has to do with the environment in the two cases.  For instance, the current directory may be different when you run your script directly vs. when it is run from the batch file.

Comment: @BrenBarn, we hit that problem already, so we should be safe from it, but I'll double check

Comment: From my own experience it doesn't matter much -- except there's no `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` with `pythonw`.

Comment: Try running directly, without use a batch file. I don't think pythonw is the problem. I think, calling the pythonw through a batch file might be generating obscure things that has to do with processes and signals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problems I would expect would be in:

- print
- stdin
- stdout
- **raw_input**

Comment: If there are print statements, could that cause issues elsewhere?

Comment: Not on prints - `raw_input` and reading from `stdin` yes but not on `print` - I use print all over the place and no problems - also note that if you are starting things as `.pyw` only the top level file needs to be a `.pyw` __not__ the rest that it imports - so it is good practice to have a main file that just does a couple of imports and then starts the rest of your code - you can then have one `.py` and one `.pyw` and you are good to go!